How to configure ts-jest to use tsx as loader?
AFAIK ts-jest uses ts-node as loader.
In my project (a monorepo with pacakges depending on each other, not recurvsively) tsx is able to load imported packages from the monorepo, but jest is not.
I spent several hours reading documentations and articles; let me skip reporting all the attempts I did as they are not relevant for this question (anyway they are recapped here).
Now thinking about tsx I would like to try to configure ts-jest to use it as loader.
Unfortunately the bad name of this exceptional product makes really hard to find relevant articles about it: if we try to search for it on google or here on stack overflow we get lots of results about react.js and (if we are lucky) a couple of interesting results.
So, I need to post this question: do you know if is it possible to configure ts-jest to use tsx as loader?
